# Is it possible to send more than one element in an array

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

**I'm trying to do this:**

> $_POST['year'] is a year. I want to get this year and the year-1 to do
>   my read

```
$year_nb = intval($_POST['year']);
$books = $this->book_model->read("*", array('year_edition' =>($_POST['year'] && ($year_nb - 1))));
```

I don't know why it doesn't work...
It's working if I do:

```
$year_nb = intval($_POST['year']);
$books=$this->book_model->read("*", array(
    'year_edition' => ($year_nb - 1)
));
```

or

```
$annee_nb = intval($_POST['year']);
$books = $this->book_model->read("*", array('year_edition' => $_POST['year']));
```

> but i need both of the years

My model:

```
public function read($selection = "*", $conditions = array(),   $champs_order = "titre", $direction_ordre = "ASC", $nombre_limite = "", $debut_limite = NULL) {
    $retour = $this->db->select($selection)
              ->from($this->table)
              ->where($conditions) 
              ->order_by($champs_order, $direction_ordre)
              ->limit($nombre_limite, $debut_limite)
              ->get()
              ->result_array();
    return $retour;
}
```

thanks for your answers

Comment: try `$books=$this->book_model->read("*", array('year_edition' => array($_POST['year'], ( $year_nb - 1) ) );`

Comment: && is a the logical [AND operator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), it "returns" `true` if and only if both operands are true. So, this is out of the question here and won't work anyway. What you have to pass to the method read() depends on what `book_model` is. Looks like an object from an ORM (object-relational mapping) library/framework. Which one do you use?